# Linear model for testing a ratio of ratios

Tags: r, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, lm

Our experimental design is as follows:

For each of two genotypes (wt and ko), we perform two different gene expression assays (Assay1 and Assay2), and do 4 replicates of each assay. We are interested in knowing if the true proportion of geneA.ko/geneA.wt significantly deviates from 1. However, the catch is that the true abundance we are seeking requires us to normalize the ratio of *geneA.ko.Assay1/geneA.wt.Assay1* by the ratio *geneA.ko.Assay2/geneA.wt.Assay2*. In other words, what we want to know is if the following ratio
deviates significantly from 1: *(geneA.ko.Assay1/geneA.wt.Assay1) / (geneA.ko.Assay2/geneA.wt.Assay2)*.

Here are three sample datasets in R that I hope illustrate the structure of the data:

```
set.seed(555)
#Not significant, because the ratio of ratios is ~ (500/50)/(10000/1000) = 1
NS = data.frame(geneID=rep(c("geneA.Rep1","geneA.Rep2","geneA.Rep3","geneA.Rep4"),4),
geno = c(rep("wt",4),rep("ko",4),rep("wt",4),rep("ko",4)),
assay = c(rep("Assay1",8),rep("Assay2",8)),
 intensity = 
   c(rnorm(4,50,5),
    rnorm(4,500,5),
    rnorm(4,1000,5),
    rnorm(4,10000,5)
  )
)

#Significant, because the ratio of ratios is ~ 6
S = data.frame(geneID=rep(c("geneA.Rep1","geneA.Rep2","geneA.Rep3","geneA.Rep4"),4),
 geno = c(rep("wt",4),rep("ko",4),rep("wt",4),rep("ko",4)),
 assay = c(rep("Assay1",8),rep("Assay2",8)),
 intensity = 
   c(rnorm(4,25,5),
    rnorm(4,150,5),
    rnorm(4,1000,5),
    rnorm(4,1000,5)
  )
)
#Also significant, because the ratio of ratios is ~ 60
S2 = data.frame(geneID=rep(c("geneA.Rep1","geneA.Rep2","geneA.Rep3","geneA.Rep4"),4),
 geno = c(rep("wt",4),rep("ko",4),rep("wt",4),rep("ko",4)),
 assay = c(rep("Assay1",8),rep("Assay2",8)),
 intensity = 
   c(rnorm(4,25,5),
    rnorm(4,150,5),
    rnorm(4,1000,5),
    rnorm(4,100,5)
  )
)
```

Our collaborator recommended using log-linear modeling to determine if the fit to the data is improved by incorporating the Assay2 terms. Unfortunately, I have very little experience with linear modeling beyond basic differential expression analysis. So far I have tried doing the following:

```
model1 = lm(intensity ~ geno, data = NS, na.action = na.omit)
model2 = lm(intensity ~ geno * assay, data = NS, na.action = na.omit)
anova(model1, model2)
```

But the fact that the p-value returned from the anova here is still <<<<< .05 suggests that my model is asking the wrong question. Any insight would be hugely appreciated. I'd be happy to go into more detail on other approaches I've tried if it's useful.